# Slick 2D vertical string orientation

Tags: java, lwjgl, slick2d

I'm trying to rotate a string that I drew of 90°.

This is an example that what I've done:

I declared a font:

```
TrueTypeFont fontButton;
Font awtFont;    
InputStream inputStream = ResourceLoader.getResourceAsStream("font/VarsityPlaybook-DEMO.ttf");

awtFont = Font.createFont(java.awt.Font.TRUETYPE_FONT, inputStream);
awtFontButton = awtFont.deriveFont(28f);
fontButton = new TrueTypeFont(awtFontButton, true);
```

And I used it in render method like this:

```
fontButton.drawString(x,y,"stringToRotate",Color.black);
```

Now I want rotate this string of 90°. Any suggestion?

Comment: Is it java Swing or Android?

Comment: No, I'm using slick2d and lwjgl libraries

Comment: Uh... glRotate3f(90,0,0,1)?

Comment: I tried to use this solution too, but slick don't render anything after that